# Accessing nested_form field values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, nested-form-for

I am using nested forms and I would like to format the text_field using `number_with_precision`. However, I'm having a problem understanding how to hook into that value. It works in the parent form. As can see below, I have tried to use the `thing` object itself (which I thought would be the correct way). Where am I going wrong?

```
= bootstrap_nested_form_for @quote, label_errors: true, label_col: "col-sm-2", control_col: "col-sm-6" do |f|
  =f.text_field :primary_fee, value: (@quote.primary_fee > 0 ? number_with_precision(@quote.primary_fee, precision: 2) : "20.00"), prepend: "<i class='fa fa-dollar'></i>".html_safe, control_col: "col-md-6"

  = f.fields_for :things, :wrapper => false, label_errors: true, html: {class: 'form_inline'} do |thing|
    = thing.text_field :price, value: number_with_precision(thing.price, precision: 2), prepend: "<i class='fa fa-dollar'></i>".html_safe, label: "Cost", class: "input-sm"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thing` in your case is a form object (containing whole bunch of data), so you should access the object of the `thing`, not thing itself.

`thing.object.price` would work:

```
= thing.text_field :price,
  input_html: { value: number_with_precision(thing.object.price, precision: 2) }
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw the reference of 'object' before, but I didn't think 'object' was literal. I thought the reference I saw was through a join table.

Comment: yeah, strange stuff, but now you'll remember :)

Comment: @Beengie please consider accepting the answer, if that solved the issue

Comment: I was going to accept the answer. You were just so fast I had to wait for the 5 min timer. lol